# Is it possible to write to settings.json in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to write into the settings.json file in Meteor? What is the standard practice in storing settings values/variables in Meteor framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, writing to `settings.json` is not possible. In most deployment solutions source files are bundled together and not writable, and even if they are – Meteor won't automatically pick up your changes.

To save a variable you need to store it in some kind of data store. Your default Mongo database is the natural candidate.

---

Example:

```
// Initialize

Settings = new Meteor.Collection('settings');

Settings.insert({
  _id: 'default',
});

// Set a variable

Settings.update('default', {$set: {
  meaningOfLife: 42,
}});

// Get a variable

Settings.findOne('default').meaningOfLife;
```

Comment: thanks. can you elaborate or give more example what is the best practice for putting the configurations in the database? I mean should I lump them into one collection? Example is highly appreciated.

Comment: Into one collection, or event one object. See the added example.